# the advertising committee : Present participle or gerund?

Tags: grammar

Plans for the **advertising** committee

1. gerund
2. present participle

Which one is correct?

Comment: Are you asking which is the correct term to describe the word "advertising" in this case? Or are you asking about a possible difference in meaning depending on which term is correct?

Comment: the correct term

Answer (score 2):

A present participle modifying a noun usually indicates that the noun performs that action. If the committee advertises, then "advertising" could be considered a present participle.

A gerund modifying a noun usually indicates that the noun is used to perform the action (drinking fountain, frying pan, steering wheel, etc.) or represents a place at which the action occurs (watering hole, parking lot, dining room, etc.). If the committee is used to advertise, then "advertising" could be considered a gerund.

Note that some people will analyze this differently. For example, many people minimize the distinction between present participles and gerunds, referring instead to "gerund-participles" (or similar terms).

Comment: I agree with the previous answer.  Commonly, a term like "advertising committee" is understood as being a "committee in charge of advertising," rather than a "committee performing advertising."  As such, most traditional grammarians would consider this the usage of the gerund.  For instance, you could expand the expression to "social media advertising committee," which can only be understood as a gerund.  But again, there is bleed over between the semantics of present participles and gerunds and so not all linguistics agree with these distinctions.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Yes, I agree that, considering how "advertising committee" is usually used, gerund is more likely than present participle.

Comment: Is it reasonable to think that the 'advertising' comes from a gerund which has been fixed in its usage as a noun?

Comment: @BEBYGONES I wouldn't call "advertising" a noun. Gerunds belong to the class of "nominals", which also include nouns, many pronouns, nominal (or "content") clauses, etc. They can function adjectivally (i.e., to modify other nominals), as "advertising" does here. (Other ways also exist to describe this situation, so you may get different answers from other people.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Firstly most modern grammars don't distinguish between the types of "-ing" verbs.

However in this phrase, "Advertising" is most easily understood as a noun.

Consider the other committees:  Sales committee, Finance committee, Production committee.  These are all formed with noun adjuncts.  There's no reason to suppose "Advertising committee" should be any different:

> The role of the advertising committee is to create all the advertising for the company.

Comment: Thx. So where do you think the 'advertising' in 'advertising committee' comes from?

Comment: Is it reasonable to think that the 'advertising' comes from a gerund which has been fixed in its usage as a noun?